# Sitecore Form Scripts aren't being Loaded after Form Submission

Tags: sitecore-forms, javascript

So, before submitting a form, my web page loaded all the form-related scripts completely. However, after the form is submitted, the page went blank and only displaying the form element, and it got redirected to "mysite.com/formbuilder?fxb.FormItemId=xxxx". I also saw "jQuery is not defined" error in the console. Already tried the Sitecore guide to [add form to a webpage](https://doc.sitecore.com/developers/90/sitecore-experience-management/en/add-a-form-to-a-webpage.html), however, the issue still remains.

Any idea on why this keeps happening? FYI, I'm using Sitecore 9.1

Comment: 'Is Ajax' checkbox is checked in on your form, right? Have you tried with unchecked ?

Comment: Can you share the MVC Outer Layout you created? and any other code that can help us spot the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I too have got this problem. You can try troubleshooting with the below steps that worked for me :

Make sure the default script files used in the form validations are present in webroot/scInstance.dev.local/sitecore modules/Web/ExperienceForms/scripts.

Check whether you've called the below scripts in the head section of the MVCOuterLayout.cshtml (I have added in this file under /Views/Shared) with its corresponding using namespace. Refer the full content of my **MVCOuterLayout.cshtml** file at the end.

```
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html

<head>
   @Html.RenderFormStyles()
   @Html.RenderFormScripts()
</head>
```

In your website layout, make sure you have set the path of this outerlayout as below :

```
@using Sitecore.Mvc
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
@using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
@model RenderingModel
@{
  Layout = "Shared/MVCOuterLayout.cshtml"; // here
}
```

Full content of my **MVCOuterLayout.cshtml**

```
 @using Sitecore.Mvc
 @using Sitecore.Mvc.Analytics.Extensions
 @using Sitecore.Mvc.Presentation
 @using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html
 @model RenderingModel
 @{
    Layout = null;
 }
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
 <head>
    <title>@Html.Sitecore().Field("title", new { DisableWebEdit = true })</title>
    @Html.RenderFormStyles()
    @Html.RenderFormScripts()
 </head>
 <body>
     @RenderBody()
 </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT :** (Tip) A  much simple and straight-forward approach of getting this done is to add these code directly in your website layout file itself :

**WebsiteLayout.cshtml**

```
@using ...
@using ....
@using Sitecore.ExperienceForms.Mvc.Html // required namespace 

<head>
    @Html.RenderFormStyles() //call them here
    @Html.RenderFormScripts() //call them here
    ....
</head>
```